# Keep track of active objects over time

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, postgresql-9.5, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of events (with `id` used as event id) like below (see also [SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3c144/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE ext (
  key INT,
  id CHAR(1),
  pid INT,
  sid INT, 
  oid INT,
  event VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO ext (key, id, pid, sid, oid, event)
VALUES 
 (1, 'Q', 1, 81, 20, 'tsu'),
 (2, 'Q', 1, 81, 9, 'tsu'),
 (3, 'Q', 1, 81, 10, 'tsu'),
 (4, 'Q', 1, 81, 4, 'tsu'),
 (5, 'Q', 1, 81, 15, 'tsu'),
 (6, 'Q', 1, 81, 3, 'tsu'),
 (7, 'Q', 1, 81, 5, 'tsu'),
 (8, 'Q', 1, 81, 18, 'tsu'),
 (9, 'Q', 1, 81, 2, 'tsu'),
 (10, 'Q', 1, 81, 1, 'tsu'),
 (11, 'Q', 1, 81, 7, 'tsu'),
 (12, 'f', 2, 2, NULL, 's'),
 (13, 'Z', 2, 871, NULL, 'e'),
 (14, 'm', 3, 872, 2, 'pof'),
 (15, 's', 3, 873, 31, 'pom'),
 (16, 'R', 3, 874, 15, 'fc'),
 (17, 'R', 3, 874, 1, 'fc'),
 (18, 'R', 3, 874, 31, 'fc'),
 (19, 'R', 3, 874, 9, 'fc'),
 (20, 'R', 3, 874, 10, 'fc'),
 (21, 'R', 3, 874, 4, 'fc'),
 (22, 'R', 3, 874, 7, 'fc'),
 (23, 'R', 3, 874, 3, 'fc'),
 (24, 'R', 3, 874, 5, 'fc'),
 (25, 'R', 3, 874, 18, 'fc'),
 (26, 'R', 3, 874, 20, 'fc'),
 (27, 'k', 3, 876, NULL, 's'),
 (28, 'a', 3, 950, 31, 'rco'),
 (29, 'y', 3, 1285, 7, 'pof'),
 (30, 'N', 3, 1286, 22, 'pom'),
 (31, 'i', 3, 1299, 1, 'fc'),
 (32, 'i', 3, 1299, 5, 'fc'),
 (33, 'i', 3, 1299, 3, 'fc'),
 (34, 'i', 3, 1299, 20, 'fc'),
 (35, 'i', 3, 1299, 4, 'fc'),
 (36, 'i', 3, 1299, 9, 'fc'),
 (37, 'i', 3, 1299, 10, 'fc'),
 (38, 'i', 3, 1299, 22, 'fc'),
 (39, 'i', 3, 1299, 15, 'fc'),
 (40, 'i', 3, 1299, 18, 'fc'),
 (41, 'I', 3, 1407, 9, 'pof'),
 (42, 'T', 3, 1408, 19, 'pom'),
 (43, 'u', 3, 1575, 4, 'pof'),
 (44, 'V', 3, 1576, 30, 'pom'),
 (45, 'B', 3, 2019, NULL, 'e'),
 (46, 'h', 4, 60, NULL, 'e');
```

The events are ordered according to `pid` and `sid` columns (you can view them, for example, as days and hours respectively in the sense that pid is bigger time unit than sid so you should order first by pid and then by sid to obtain correct order). As you can see, some events (`event = tsu` or `event = fc`) have more than one row as they refer to many objects (`oid`), some refer to only one object (as the event of `id = m`), and some have only one row, but they actually refer to all previously observed object which are not 'dead'. They are some additional rules:

- an object is dead when they hit the `pof` or `rco` event (as stated in `event` column)
- when the object hits the `pof` event, there is another object that replaces it marked with `pom` event

I need to keep track of currently active objects. Therefore I'd like to "cross join" the rows where `oid` is `NULL` with all the active objects that can be deduced from the previous events, where by "cross join" I mean to replicate the row with `oid = NULL` for every currently active `oid`.

As the logic may be hard to grasp from the text, I have prepared the expected output (available on [SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1c8c4/4)):

```
CREATE TABLE intermediate_result (
  id CHAR(1),
  pid INT,
  sid INT, 
  oid INT,
  event VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO intermediate_result (id, pid, sid, oid, event)
VALUES 
 ('Q', 1, 81, 20, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 9, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 10, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 4, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 15, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 3, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 5, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 18, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 2, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 1, 'tsu'),
 ('Q', 1, 81, 7, 'tsu'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 20, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 9, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 10, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 4, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 15, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 3, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 5, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 18, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 2, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 1, 's'),
 ('f', 2, 2, 7, 's'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 20, 'e'), 
 ('Z', 2, 871, 9, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 10, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 4, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 15, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 3, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 5, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 18, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 2, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 1, 'e'),
 ('Z', 2, 871, 7, 'e'),
 ('m', 3, 872, 2, 'pof'),
 ('s', 3, 873, 31, 'pom'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 15, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 1, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 31, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 9, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 10, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 4, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 7, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 3, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 5, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 18, 'fc'),
 ('R', 3, 874, 20, 'fc'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 15, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 1, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 31, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 9, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 10, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 4, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 7, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 3, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 5, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 18, 's'),
 ('k', 3, 876, 20, 's'),
 ('a', 3, 950, 31, 'rco'),
 ('y', 3, 1285, 7, 'pof'),
 ('N', 3, 1286, 22, 'pom'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 1, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 5, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 3, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 20, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 4, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 9, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 10, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 22, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 15, 'fc'),
 ('i', 3, 1299, 18, 'fc'),
 ('I', 3, 1407, 9, 'pof'),
 ('T', 3, 1408, 19, 'pom'),
 ('u', 3, 1575, 4, 'pof'),
 ('V', 3, 1576, 30, 'pom'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 1, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 5, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 3, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 20, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 30, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 19, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 10, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 22, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 15, 'e'),
 ('B', 3, 2019, 18, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 1, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 5, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 3, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 20, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 30, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 19, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 10, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 22, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 15, 'e'),
 ('h', 4, 60, 18, 'e');
```

The SQL version is PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: It would be informative if you showed us the primary key (or candidate key) of the table, and maybe the *meaning* of the columns.

Comment: The table doesn't have a primary key, but a combination of `id`, `tid` and `oid` could form a valid primary key. I can't disclose the *exact meaning* behind the columns, but speaking in the abstract terms: the table consists of many events (with event id marked as `id`, and event type marked as `event`). The event can impact many objects (`oid`), but can also refer only to one object. The combination of `pid` and `sid` columns record timing of events and therefore could be used to order table. `tid` actually refers to group of object, but it is constant (and reduntant) in the example

Comment: A table without a primary key has no meaning. Add the (natural) key. It appears there is some ordering (in time) present (otherwise you would not have *events*), so at least one of the key components should have a time-like role. And: if columns are redundant for the example: leave them out!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *A table without a primary key has no meaning.*. Why?  But to comply with your comment I have added `key` column with subsequent natural numbers and removed spare columns. As I mentioned before, the ordering is given by a combination of `pid` and `sid`. Please consider revoking close vote if this is from you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization (and your `key` column is a *surrogate key* : it does not add information, only identity)

Comment: `all previously observed object` -->> please define *previous* What is the *time* column?

Comment: `pid` and `sid` are time columns. You can treat them as, for example, days and hours respectively in the sense that `pid` is bigger time unit than `sid` so you should order first by `pid` and then by `sid` to obtain correct order.

Comment: Why is `(46, 'h', 4, 60, NULL, 'e')` - the last row in table `ext` - missing from the result?

Comment: I really wish I could downvote twice. This question is worse than suboptimal.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `(46, 'h', 4, 60, NULL, 'e')` should indeed be in the expected output - I fixed it. I also added information about ordering to the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: The only remaining mystery for me: Why do the rows expanded from row 46 all have oid NULL?

Comment: You're right, should be expanded with every "current" `oid` - corrected.

Answer (score 2):

This is very hard and inefficient to solve with SQL alone. I think your best option is a procedural solution.

Here is an implementation in PL/pgSQL.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_expand_oid_null()
  RETURNS TABLE(_id CHAR(1), _pid int, _sid int, _oid int, _event varchar(3))
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _key   int;
   _pof   int;  -- remember for subsequent 'pom'
BEGIN
   -- hold set of "active object IDs
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_active_objects(
     oid int PRIMARY KEY
   , pid int
   , sid int
   , key int
   ) ON COMMIT DROP;

-- loop table rows in order
   FOR _key, _id, _pid, _sid, _oid, _event IN
      SELECT e.key, e.id, e.pid, e.sid, e.oid, e.event
      FROM   ext e
      ORDER  BY e.pid, e.sid, e.key
   LOOP
      IF _oid IS NULL THEN
         -- expand to ordered set of active objects
         RETURN QUERY
         SELECT _id, _pid, _sid, a.oid, _event 
         FROM   tmp_active_objects a
         ORDER  BY a.pid, a.sid, a.key;  -- keep original order of events
         -- returns nothing if no active objects
      ELSE
         RETURN QUERY VALUES (_id, _pid, _sid, _oid, _event);
         
         CASE _event
         WHEN 'rco' THEN
            DELETE FROM tmp_active_objects WHERE oid = _oid;
         WHEN 'pof' THEN
            _pof = _oid;   -- remember for subsequent 'pom'
         WHEN 'pom' THEN
            UPDATE tmp_active_objects
            SET    oid = _oid
            WHERE  oid = _pof;
         ELSE
            -- upsert active objects
            INSERT INTO tmp_active_objects (oid, pid, sid, key)
            VALUES (_oid, _pid, _sid, _key)
            ON CONFLICT (oid) DO
            UPDATE
            SET    (pid, sid, key)
                 = (EXCLUDED.pid, EXCLUDED.sid, EXCLUDED.key);
         END CASE;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f099a9afd82f11ee09ad4f7719d0dc9b)*

Explaining everything is even more work than writing it. There are a couple of assumptions I made and pitfalls to avoid. In particular, every 'pof' row must be followed by a 'pom' row immediately.

If you are not firm with PL/pgSQL, consider a paid consultant. Or implement in a procedural language of your choice.

Comment: @wildplasser: Yeah the explanation is a mess, and that can be infuriating when trying to understand and help. But give the OP some credit for *trying*. He provided a usable test case including fiddles, formatted properly and reacted to requests. That's more than most do. If he wouldn't be confused with all of this, he wouldn't be here. Anyway, trying to understand the question made an answer form in my head. Didn't want to let it go to waste.

Comment: @wildplasser: And my little pet peeve: The question provided the Postgres version up front. Gets a plus point in my book.

Comment: many thanks for that! Rows with key 45 and 46 should be in fact expanded as well. I'm not sure what you mean by rows with key 14 and 15 terminating the series, but let me try to clarify further on that: events `pof` and `pom` are actually related in the sens that you can treat `pof` as 'off' event for the particular `oid` and, as it becomes replaced with the `oid` from `pom` event, `pom` is 'on' event for the latter.

Comment: For example, in row with key 41 object 9 is dead and replaced with object 19. Despite being in the last expanded list of object before that event (keys 31 to 40), object 9 should be absent in the expanded rows for key 45 and object 19 should be present then. I hope that makes more sense now, but let me know if any further explanations help!

Comment: @jakes: I think I see clearly now. Consider the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! It's a pity though that the previous solution couldn't be adjusted to solve for the last rows as it was much easier to follow. Nevertheless, I really appreciate the effort you put in this.

Comment: @jakes My previous version was based on a misunderstanding and only happened to produce a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get into the SQLFiddle to see the problem correctly.

Main request should be restated to say that you would like to cross join active objects with null values for oid while retaining all rows for all non-null oid values

**Understanding:**

1. The oid value represents the object
2. From the result data, active objects are dependent on time so to calculate active objects, we will depend on particular time Row IDs which will represent time.
3. The table inserts are time-related and are going into the future with later rows representing future times
4. Question: The relevance of a pom object replacement in light of the main request is still not fully understood and didn't have any bearing on the solution.

**Solution:**

For the solution, there are 3 parts -

1. An auto-incremented field added to your ext table. You already added it as an INT and called it Key. This will be used as a unique TimeID

```
With DistinctTimeIDs as
(
  select a.key as TimeID from ext a
)
```

2. Active objects - History does matter. In this case, we want all non-null oids before a particular TimeID without pof or rco events. This will for each TimeID in the dataset, list all Active oids before that TimeID.

```
ActiveObjects as 
( 
  select b.TimeID, a.oid from ext a inner join DistinctTimeIDs b on b.TimeID>=a.key
  where oid is not null 
  and not exists (select 'x' from ext where key<b.TimeID and event in ('pof', 'rco') and oid=a.oid) 
  and a.key = (select MAX(c.key) from ext c where c.key<b.TimeID and c.event not in ('pof', 'rco') and c.oid=a.oid)
)
```

3. Null object value rows

```
With NullObjectValues as 
(
  select * from ext a 
  where a.oid is null 
)
```

Putting it all together, we will merge non-null object rows with null object rows cross joined with active objects for each TimeID

```
With DistinctTimeIDs as
(
  select a.key as TimeID from ext a
), ActiveObjects as 
( 
  select b.TimeID, a.oid from ext a inner join DistinctTimeIDs b on b.TimeID>=a.key
  where oid is not null 
  and not exists (select 'x' from ext where key<b.TimeID and event in ('pof', 'rco') and oid=a.oid) 
  and a.key = (select MAX(c.key) from ext c where c.key<b.TimeID and c.event not in ('pof', 'rco') and c.oid=a.oid)
), NullObjectValues as 
(
  select * from ext a 
  where a.oid is null 
)
select a.key ,a.id,a.pid,a.sid,a.oid,a.event from ext a where a.oid is not null
union all
select a.key ,a.id,a.pid,a.sid,b.oid,a.event from NullObjectValues a CROSS JOIN ActiveObjects b
where b.TimeID = a.key 
order by 1;
```

SQL Fiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2fb57/2

Comment: I like your solution as this cross join with active objects is something I had in mind, but couldn't solidify an idea. I have some trouble to understand ActiveObjects definition though - could you elaborate on that step by step and explain in more details how exactly where clause works here? I mean the part I have trouble to grasp is why ActiveObjects accumulates more and more objects for the initial TimeIDs (less than 12)

Comment: The other thing is that the rows with `pom` events should be in fact included in ActiveObjects for TimeID of 30, 42 and 44, but to be fair that doesn't seem to affect the final result.

Comment: So simply speaking, every row represents a point in time. So the first thing is to get all the points in time - The TimeID.
Secondly for that point in time, we need to fetch all oids that do not have pom or rco events. This is this part:

select b.TimeID, a.oid from ext a inner join DistinctTimeIDs b on b.TimeID>=a.key
  where oid is not null 
  and not exists (select 'x' from ext where key<b.TimeID and event in ('pof', 'rco') and oid=a.oid)

Comment: Now if I have an oid occuring multiple times before a Time ID, I want to only see it once because I care about active objects not active object occurences. That's what this part is for:

and a.key = (select MAX(c.key) from ext c where c.key<b.TimeID and c.event not in ('pof', 'rco') and c.oid=a.oid).

Comment: Since we now have for each Time ID, a list of active objects for it, when we cross join with the null oids (which also have a TimeID), we can be sure that even if we cross join, we can still join and restrict on time ID so that only the active oids for that Time ID are used in the cross join.

Comment: As for the pom events, they are part of active objects because they are not restricted as long as they don't belong to their own unique time. If they do belong to their own unique TimeID, it would be a simple matter of changing key<b.TimeID to key<=b.TimeID everywhere in the active object with statement but then it may not match your query. Anyway, hope it all helps.

Comment: For this "I mean the part I have trouble to grasp is why ActiveObjects accumulates more and more objects for the initial TimeIDs (less than 12)", the simplest way to explain it is probably birth rate and death rate. At any time, if less people are dying than are being born, population increases. I am using each row/event as my timeID which means I have 46 different times (not less than 12). For each one, I just figure out how many active oids exist before it. In your scenario, there are less objects dying than new so it accumulates. Using times will only work if those times are unique keys